# How to show traffic from specific domain in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm just wondering if it's possible to show traffic from a specific domain only in the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: For filter by Domain, type **Domain:www.domain.com** in filter box.

Comment: domain must be lowercase, like `a darren` said

Comment: To filter by host and port: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64263874

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes you can, by entering `domain:localhost` in the filter box to filter by the `localhost` domain, for example:

[image]

Notes:

- The filter box has autocompletion to help you out (which is how I found this feature)
- Also helpful to filter by the type of request / file type e.g. XHR

Comment: how can I filter except for this domain?

Comment: you can now click 'Invert' to exclude what you're filtering

Comment: Thank you @darren, the toggle button was right next to it! ‍♂️
I ended up writing a script for it that makes use of performance interface
https://gist.github.com/ankurparihar/5b82717e6bea4c13ba861e22e854d035

Answer (score 14):

Just type in part of the domain and check the filter box. Also, you can turn on the Domain column by right-clicking on the top:

[image]

Comment: this is not a good solution. other domains may have request content related to the domain name. then it's just a mess. a darren's reply is the correct one. can't believe this has 5 upvotes

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use domain in filter, like this:

> domain:yourdomain.com