# How to slow down a specific file loading in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, race-condition

I am trying to test some race condition in chrome, in my local environment, file A always loaded up before an ajax call, so I would like to see if there is a network latency, what will my page behave.

Is there anyway that I can slow down a single file load?

There is another question similar to mine but not exactly the same. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422640/how-to-show-traffic-from-specific-domain-in-chrome-dev-tools)

I can put my file in somewhere else in another domain, and then slow down this specific domain, but that's just too much effort for this simple problem. So I wonder anyone knows a better solution.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: `setTimeout` ? or if you need to be sure request1 is made after request2, `request2.onload=performRequest1`

Comment: Use Network throttling from chrome dev-tools? That will slow down all the traffic but might solve your problem

Comment: @Kaiido I need to test my code whether I can handle situation like that, so I can not use `request2.onload=perfomRequest1`. `setTimeout` might be a solution...

Comment: @UG_ I can't do that. If I slow down all the traffic, the loading order will still be the same, then I can not test my code whether it can handle the race condition.

Comment: Well if all you change is when these requests are made, you'll see if your remaining logic holds. I don't see why you can't use onload for testing

Comment: @Kaiido My code need to deal with two async operations, one is loading script from s3, the other one is an rest api call. I want to do some logic after these two things all finished, but the order can not be promised. Currently if I do the testing, the script was always loaded before the api call finished, so I want to slow down the script loading to see the behavior of my code when the script loaded after the api call finished. Does this make sense to you? Apologize I didn't make this clear in the description.

Comment: That was already clear to me in your question. You currently have something like (pseudo-code) `onReqEnd => if(++loaded == 2) doTheRemaining();}; asyncRequest1().then(onReqEnd) asyncRequest2().then(onReqEnd)` But request1 always ends before. So for your testing, you can just do `asyncRequest2().then(=>asynRequest1().then(doTheReamaining))`. Like this you are sure that the order is different from what you had.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, this will give me the order I want, but this way totally changed my code that I want to test, then it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well if the one part of your code you want to test is `doTheReamining` it shouldn't matter how what happened previously did happen

Comment: @Kaiido If you throttle and file is big it will take more time to download and perhaps at some point download after the other request

Comment: How are you loading the script? Can you post an example?

Comment: @Kaiido suggesting someone rewrites their code for testing purposes does not fly in any good development environment, it may be useful for ad-hoc testing as you're developing, but if testing the order of async responses received does not matter forms part of your testing cases for any formal testing past unit testing, then you need a way of simulating this without just rewriting your code.