# How can I filter by host and port in Chrome's developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Debugging local app and would like to trace all calls to the backend running on `localhost:8080`.  It's possible to filter on `domain=localhost`; however, this also grabs a ton of noise from calls to frontend assets running on `localhost:9999`.  Is there any way to either include the port 8080 in the filter, or at least exclude port 9999?

[image]

`domain:localhost:8080` doesn't work...

---

**Related**: it would also be helpful to filter on part of a path.  For example, `localhost:8080/foo/bar/baz` ... if I could just filter on `*bar*` or `*bar/baz*` that would also do the trick.

Comment: Try `url:localhost:8080` or simply `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Neither of these worksin my current chrome browser - do they in yours or were you just speculating?

Comment: Oh, it's a [new one](https://crrev.com/c/2318146). Works in Chrome Canary/dev.

Comment: `domain:locahost` you should be able to type in `domain:localhost xxxxx/yyyy` and it will filter

Comment: Thanks @epascrello - `domain:localhost /bar` was sufficient for me.  I guess filtering on the path is more robust than filtering on the port!

Do you want to post this as an answer so that I can mark as accepted?

Comment: `url:http://localhost:8000` worked for me, Chrome even autocomplete it. Version: `89.0.4389.72 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Use the url filter.

Domain filter will only filter on the hostname without the port. You'll have to use the url filter instead. For example, `url:localhost:3000`.

[image]