Where does the Chrome DevTools network request filter box search?
The Filter input on the Network tab of Chrome's DevTools can find requests by all kinds of properties, but when you don't use any of those keywords, what does it look for then?
I always assumed it does a full text search in the whole request (headers and body) but now I found that it doesn't - for example it does not search in the host name if you don't specify the url: keyword.

" for example it does not search in the host name if you don't specify the url: keyword.". Hmm that's odd. I always thought it did for me and I just tried it on some random site that communicated with external hostnames, and i can filter by them with no keywords.

@adsy Ok, there seems to be something else at play. My page loads from localhost:1234 and accesses localhost:1235. Without url: I cannot find it by either local or 1235. With url: I can. I can also find other host names, without url:.

I think theres possibly something weird about it when ports are involved. Doesnt explain everything but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263874/how-can-i-filter-by-host-and-port-in-chromes-developer-tools is a bit unusual.
